# Get array value response from php in ext js

Tags: php, extjs

How do I get the value from this object in EXT JS?!

```
{ "success" : "Some text message." }
```

I'm trying this :

```
success : function(resp, request) {
    Ext.Msg.alert('alert title', resp.responseText);
}
```

Comment: Try with `Ext.decode(resp.responseText)`

Answer (score 1):

it depends on what are you using to communicate with server
if you are using `Ext.Ajax.request`:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: 'page.php',
    params: {
        id: 1
    },
    success: function(response){
        var text = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
        alert(text.success)
        // process server response here
    }
});
```

but if you are using form.submit(), `success` in json must be true or false, it indicates was response successful or not.